# Почему клик по кнопке обновляет страницу?

Tags: html, jquery, css

Посредством JQuery привязал событие к классу вот этого объекта:

```
<button class="form__close-open-button"><p>свернуть поля ввода</p></button>
```

При клике присваивается нужный класс другому объекту, но почему-то обновляется страница и эффект обнуляется. В чём причина?

Comment: Возможно, потому что она у вас в форме находится

Comment: Добавьте больше кода, так как не понятно где находится кнопка, а возможно, что проблема в обработчике клика.

Comment: Да, кнопка находится в форме. Я не знаю этой тонкости.

Comment: А код простой:

$(document).ready(function(){
 $('.form__close-open-button').on('click', function(){
  $('.form__inputs').toggleClass('js-trigger');
 });
});

Comment: Добавьте в обработчик кнопки return false; это приведет к тому что форма отправляться не будет.

Answer (score 2):

Укажите кнопке тип, `<button type="button">` , по умолчанию у всех кнопок `type="submit"`, что и
производит отправку форм.

> [HTML Living Standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type)
>
> The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.

Всегда указуйте тип для кнопок, даже если она не в форме, это хорошая практика.

Comment: Спасибо, Александр. Ценный совет.

Comment: а где написано что type="submit" для button это по умолчанию ?

Comment: [screenshot](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1TNC2q59iRgT13kJu5qK4R2pZiBmpEhP9)

Comment: @НикитаФаст По умолчанию это когда вообще не указан атрибут `type` браузер рассматривает ее с типом `submit`. Это прописано в спецификации. Цитата: *The missing value default and invalid value default are the Submit Button state.* ссылочка: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-elements.html#attr-button-type

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev вот я и показал скриншот того что при  не указании type кнопки ни чего  не присваевается ...а вот если не написать doctype head body то как раз это всё всё равно будет ....вот это по умолчанию

Comment: @НикитаФаст я вам ссылочку скинул на спецификацию там написанно *`Отсутствеи значения  и неверное значения по дефолту - это состояние кнопки Submit Button`*, То что шрифт черный и фот белый это тоже состояние по дефолту, если вы напишите `<input />` то это будет `type="text"` по дефолту

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev для input по умолчанию type="text" .....для button если её вынуть из form вообще ни чего не произойдёт ... а в form она очевидно что то отправляет ... я же показал скрин что `самого type нет по умолчанию` ...

Comment: @AlexanderZaytsev я спорить не хочу и не буду ....

Answer (score 1):

```html
<form action="#">
  <button onclick="return false" class="form__close-open-button"><p>свернуть поля ввода</p></button>
</form>

<!-- или же так -->

<form action="#" onsubmit="return false">
  <button class="form__close-open-button"><p>свернуть поля ввода</p></button>
</form>
```

С помощью jQuery можно сделать так:

```
<script>
  $(document).on('submit', 'form', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault(); // или же return false
  }
</script>

<form action="#">
  <button class="form__close-open-button"><p>свернуть поля ввода</p></button>
</form>
```